# Spring mongoDB GeoQueries

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

Hi I'm familiar with spring but not with mongoDB
i have a simple class with a GeoJsonPoint attribute called couponCoordinates

I also made an interface with the following method

```
public List<Coupon> findByCouponCoordinatesNear(Point point ,Distance distance);
```

which dies giving the following error

```
planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

I know im able to add the index manually and actually the query works well if i do so. But i have the following questions:

1. is it good practice to use GeoJsonPoint?
2. is there a way to add the index by code?
3. does it relate to the `@CompoundIndexes` annotation?

thanks

update:

Here is the created query:

```
>  main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Inserting DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, businessName, businessDescription, couponName, couponDescription, couponWhatsappNumber, couponAddress, couponCoordinates, category, active] in collection: coupon
2015-05-08 10:00:48.921 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
2015-05-08 10:00:49.389 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Inserting DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, businessName, businessDescription, couponName, couponDescription, couponWhatsappNumber, couponAddress, couponCoordinates, category, active] in collection: coupon
2015-05-08 10:00:49.390 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
2015-05-08 10:00:49.411 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "couponCoordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : { $java : Point [x=6.213700, y=-75.576700] }, "$maxDistance" : 1.567855942887398E-4 } }, Fields: null, Sort: null
2015-05-08 10:00:49.416 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "couponCoordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : { "x" : 6.2137 , "y" : -75.5767} , "$maxDistance" : 1.567855942887398E-4}} fields: null for class: class com.datasol.cuponza.model.Coupon in collection: coupon
2015-05-08 10:00:49.417 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
2015-05-08 10:00:49.436 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.r.query.**MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "couponCoordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : { $java : Point [x=6.213700, y=-75.576700] }, "$maxDistance" : 0.002351783914331097 } }, Fields: null, Sort: null**
2015-05-08 10:00:49.438 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "couponCoordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : { "x" : 6.2137 , "y" : -75.5767} , "$maxDistance" : 0.002351783914331097}} fields: null for class: class com.datasol.cuponza.model.Coupon in collection: coupon
2015-05-08 10:00:49.438 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
2015-05-08 10:00:49.443 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { } fields: null for class: class com.datasol.cuponza.model.Coupon in collection: coupon
2015-05-08 10:00:49.443 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
Cleaning repository
2015-05-08 10:00:49.446 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[cuponza]
2015-05-08 10:00:49.447 DEBUG 12228 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Remove using query: { } in collection: coupon.
```

UPDATE II
There is an annotation that  supposed to do just that
i placed it in my Coupon class (which has the @Document annotation) like this

```
@GeoSpatialIndexed(name="GeoIndex_2d")
private Point couponCoordinates;
```

but the index is not created
seems like the class MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator is not picking it up

UPDATE II
Here is the POJO

```
@Document
public class Coupon {

@Id
private String couponId;

private String businessName;

private String businessDescription;

private String couponName;

private String couponDescription;

private String couponWhatsappNumber;

private String couponAddress;

@GeoSpatialIndexed(name="GeoIndex_2d")
private Point couponCoordinates;

private CategoryEnum category;

@TextIndexed
private Set<String> keywords;

private Boolean active;

public Coupon (){}


//getters and setters
```

and here is the interface

```
public interface CouponRepository extends MongoRepository<Coupon, String> {

   public List<Coupon> findByCouponCoordinatesNear(Point point ,Distance distance);
}
```

Comment: Which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using? What's the version of your MongoDB server? Can you add the code for `Coupon` + the stacktracke. Can you enable looing for `MongoTemplate` and post the created query?

Comment: MongoDB shell version : 3.0.1 spring mongo org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.7.0.RELEASE:compile about the generated query, i suppose i have to change the log settings???

Comment: just add `<logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" level="debug" />` to your logback.xml - with that you should be able to see the query.

Comment: Christopth, i added the log but  my question is actually is if there is a way to add the index programmatically at class level using annotations (@Index.@CompoundIndex) , instead of going to the mongoDB command line and add it there , this also applies to text search where one needs to create an index

Comment: The `@GeoSpatialIndexed` annotation should be the way to go if you intend to autocreate indexes. What worries me a bit is the fact, that the query creator seems to generate a spherical query using `$nearSphere` though the actual definition is for a non spherical one. One possibility for indexes not being created might be a cyclic property reference whithin you domain types - if so there should be a message in the logs. Any chance you can point me at some code I can run?

Comment: Added the pojo and interface,no other code is involved

Comment: its still an issue.....

Comment: can you please check the `@Document` annotation. As the index creator requires you to have `@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document` while there's also `org.springframework.data.mapping.Document` which will not trigger auto setup of indexes.

Comment: i have the correct imports so it seems:                                                     org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.GeoSpatialIndexed;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.TextIndexed;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

Comment: What seems strange to me is that the MongoPersistenceEntityIndexCreator mappingContext.getPersistentEntities() is returning a null array while it should pick the Coupon class that has the @Document annotation

Comment: i was using a deprecated constructor , im now using the SimpleMongoDbFactory (MongoClient client , String dbName)

Comment: Do you resolve this issue ?